# Passing data between vanilla JS components

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say we have an app that have of 2 components - an input that takes numbers and a range slider. When value in the input component is updated, the slider is set to that value too, and vice versa. What is the best approach to do this app in vanillaJs without using React?
If I create 2 classes, how do I reactively update the state in them and how do I store these shared state?

Comment: Is this primarily about solving the problem at hand, or about writing your own "React light"?

Comment: Can you post your "*[mcve]*" code, that way we can write answers that apply to the code you're actually working with? This should make the answers more easily transferable to your environment. As well as making the answers more useful to future visitors.

Comment: You might use a class to store this data, inject that class in both components and make them always set and get the state from this class. But you'll need to always update both components if you're not using React.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for classes or shared state. You can just use a simple event handler on each element:

```js
var shared = document.querySelectorAll(".shared");

shared.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    shared.forEach(function(el) {
      el.value = e.target.value;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="shared" value="50">
<input type="range" class="shared" value="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```js
const
    $number = document.querySelector('.number'),
    $slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

$number.addEventListener('change', () => {
    $slider.value = $number.value;
})
$slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
    $number.value = $slider.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
<input type="range" class="slider" max="100" min="1" step="1" value="1" />
```

Using 'input' for the range, it will update the .number while moving the bar.